# std::vector elements are overwritten

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have a function `ReadMatFromTxt` that reads some numbers from a text file and stores them in a `vector<Mat>`. The function skips some lines, that contain headers, and saves the values between two header lines as `Mat` into the vector `M_vec`. When a header line is encountered, the values accumulated in `Mat M` until then are added to the vector `M_vec`.

```cc
vector<Mat> ReadMatFromTxt(string filename, int rows, int cols)
{
    double m;
    Mat M = Mat::zeros(rows/2, cols, CV_32FC2); //Matrix to store values
    vector<Mat> M_vec;

    ifstream in(filename.c_str());
    int lineNo = 0;
    int cnt = 0;        //index starts from 0
    string line;

    while(getline(in, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        if(((lineNo % (rows+1)) == 0) && lineNo != 0)
        // header found, add Mat to vector<Mat>
        {
            cout << M << endl;
            M_vec.push_back(M);

            cnt = 0;
            lineNo++;
        }
        else
        {
            while (iss >> m)
            {
                int temprow = cnt / cols;
                int tempcol = cnt % cols;
                if(cnt < (rows*cols)/2) {
                    M.at<Vec2f>(temprow, tempcol)[0] = m;
                } else {
                    M.at<Vec2f>(temprow - rows/2 , tempcol)[1] = m;
                }
                cnt++;
            }
        lineNo++;
        }
    }

    return M_vec;
}
```

However, when I use this function in the main, I see that all elements of the vector are the same (although the text file contains different values).

```cc
vector<Mat> M_vec;
M_vec = ReadMatFromTxt(txt_path.string(), rows, cols);

for(int i=0; i<M_vec.size(); i++)
   {
       cout << "M_vec[" << i << "] = " << M_vec[i] << endl;
   }
```

Am I doing something wrong while doing `push_back` to add `Mat` to the vector. Why is it overwritten like that?

Comment: Reproducible testcase please.

Comment: `Mat` is a reference type

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it can be clearly seen it's a type from OpenCV.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: "Clearly"? How so? There is no OpenCV tag.

Comment: @ChristianHackl now there is.

Comment: @ChristianHackl the use of `CV_32FC2` is a strong clue.

Comment: @Borgleader: If you know OpenCV, then maybe yes.

Comment: you should also fix your logic: push the matrix directly after reading it fully, not later on the next line else you might miss the last matrix in your file

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Please, do not abuse your editing privileges.

Comment: @Borgleader: That could be from literally anything. It is up to the OP to formally declare the technologies he or she is using.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot the opencv tag.

Comment: @NathanOliver: You are right. I also felt the need for being able to use the debugger. Just too many things to learn at the same time...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit adding a missing tag that was clearly forgotten isn't edit privilege abuse. If you think it is, feel free to take it to Meta. Just the fact it wasn't clear for you doesn't mean it wasn't obvious for me that the question is about OpenCV.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: It is not up to you to guess at tags, your misplaced "it was so obvious, bro" confidence notwithstanding! We ask the OP to set the appropriate tags based on what he or she is using. Guessing leads to mistakes leads to wrong answers leads to harmful advice. It's called due diligence.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wasn't guessing randomly at all. I've noticed a lot of elements hinting at OpenCV use. Again, this is not a place to discuss this matter, so please refrain from posting here and open a question on Meta instead.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The key word here, and generally on SO, is "being helpful". If your lack of expertise prevented you from spotting the missing opencv tag, maybe you should just move on to another question where you'll be able to help.

Comment: @Mr.kbok: You've _completely_ missed my point, but that's okay. I'll forgive you for making it personal and insinuating anything about my own expertise or experience. If I were 100% sure that these were OpenCV features, I'd _still_ ask **the OP** to tag it. You don't just stomp in and take that responsibility off them. Because 100% sureness doesn't entail 100% certainty. Perhaps the OP happens to have the same-named macro from some other library? Or from his own code five lines up? _You don't know_, no matter how much you prattle on about how you know OpenCV more than I do.

Comment: use a NEW "Mat M = Mat::zeros(rows/2, cols, CV_32FC2); //Matrix to store values" for each vector element, because cv::Mat is just a header for the actual matrix data so it wont be copied. OR use M_vec.push_back(M.clone() ); to create a deep-copy every time!

Comment: Thanks, I took the second option but good to know the first one as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opencv class `Mat` assignment operators and copy constructor only [modify a reference counter.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) The deep data created by `Mat::zeros(rows/2, cols, CV_32FC2)` remains the same.

To have several instance of data use

```
M_vec.push_back(M.clone());
```